# Gulp-cdnizer - Not replacing source links

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to get gulp-cdnizer to work but all it does is take in the file and spits out the file unprocessed to the destination folder. Perhaps my option settings are wrong or the gulp task isn't working. How do you configure the gulp-cdnizer to work with a custom bower_components path?

**Gulp task:**

```
gulp.task('makeCdn', function () {

    return gulp.src('./app/**/*.html')
        .pipe(cdnizer({
            bowerComponents: './vendor/bower_components',
            allowRev: true,
            allowMin: true,
                files: [
                    {
                        file: '/vendor/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
                        package: 'angular',
                        // angular has a bizarre version string inside bower, with extra information.
                        // using major.minor.patch directly ensures it works with the CDN
                        cdn: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/${ major }.${ minor }.${ patch }/angular.min.js'
                    }
                ]
            })
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
        );

});
```

**HTML file `'./app/test/test.html'`:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="/vendor/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="/vendor/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Folder Structure:**

[image: Folder Structure]

What needs to be done to get gulp-cdnizer to work?

Comment: Author here: `bower_components` is automatically determined using `.bowerrc`, if you have that set correctly.  I don't see any reason for this to be failing.  Have you tested this as you have it presented exactly?

Comment: @OverZealous I've tested exactly as it is presented with a .bowerrc file contents of `{"directory" : "./bower_components" }`. I then tried a more conventional bower install where .bowerrc and bower.json are installed in the root of the project, with the .bowercc file containing: `{"directory" : "./vendor/bower_components" }`.  Still no dice.

Comment: @OverZealous I've also tried using and not using the bowerComponents parameter in the two scenarios mentioned above. 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The one thing I see is that the `.bowerrc` file is in the wrong place — it needs to be in the root of the project, alongsige `gulpfile.js`.  This might explain why the automatic lookup for bower_components failed.  Something else is wrong, though, because bower is only used to look up version info, it's not actually part of the replacement process.

Comment: @OverZealous Hmmm. Not sure what is going on. As I described in my previous comments, I moved the `.bowerrc` and `bower.json` to the root of my project and tested that. So I think something else is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you have a couple of typos in your gulpfile.  You have everything wrapped inside the first `gulp.src().pipe()`, rather than being chained.

If you strip the arguments and whitespace, you can see what you have is this:

```js
return gulp.src(...)
    .pipe(
        cdnizer(...).pipe(gulp.dest(...))
    );
```

When it should be:

```js
return gulp.src(...)
   .pipe(cdnizer(...))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
```

Honestly, I'm not sure why this failed the way it did, but the result of `cdnizer()` was being bypassed.

Simply fix your nesting / parentheses, like so, and you'll be all set.

```js
gulp.task('makeCdn', function () {

    return gulp.src('./app/**/*.html')
        .pipe(cdnizer({
            bowerComponents: './vendor/bower_components',
            allowRev: true,
            allowMin: true,
                files: [
                    {
                        file: '/vendor/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
                        package: 'angular',
                        // angular has a bizarre version string inside bower, with extra information.
                        // using major.minor.patch directly ensures it works with the CDN
                        cdn: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/${ major }.${ minor }.${ patch }/angular.min.js'
                    }
                ]
            }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

You can also eliminate the wrapper object and default options, if your `.bowerrc` is in the right place:

```js
gulp.task('makeCdn', function () {

    return gulp.src('./app/**/*.html')
        .pipe(cdnizer([
                    {
                        file: '/vendor/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
                        package: 'angular',
                        // angular has a bizarre version string inside bower, with extra information.
                        // using major.minor.patch directly ensures it works with the CDN
                        cdn: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/${ major }.${ minor }.${ patch }/angular.min.js'
                    }
                ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

Comment: This should have been more obvious — I noticed the odd alignment of the `.pipe()` calls in your file right away, but disregarded it.  D'oh!

Comment: Wish I had seen that sooner too! I think the sample code in your `README.md` on github, might of lead me astray. It's missing a `)`. Thanks for noticing the mistake and providing a solution.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I updated the readme.  I'll republish the npm module later, too, but it's giving me a headache right this minute.