# gulp-cdnizer doesn't replace css links

Tags: javascript, gulp, cdn

I have a task to cdnize my files:

```
gulp.task('makeCdn', function () {
    gulp.src(['./Views/SharedTemplates/*.cshtml'])
                .pipe(cdnizer({
                    relativeRoot: './wwwroot/lib',
                    allowMin: true,
                    files: [
                        {
                            cdn: "google:angular"
                        },
                        {
                            cdn: "google:jquery"
                        },
                        {
                            cdn: "cdnjs:select2"
                        },
                        {
                            cdn: "cdnjs:twitter-bootstrap",
                            package: "bootstrap"
                        }
                    ]
                }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./Views/Shared/'));
});
```

It nicely converts the js references, e.g. from:

```html
  <script src="../../wwwroot/lib/select2/select2.js"></script>
```

to:

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.js"></script>
```

BUT - it leaves the css links untouched:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../wwwroot/lib/select2/select2.css" />
```

.

And an additional question, why it's making such conversion from:

```html
<script src="../../wwwroot/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../../wwwroot/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
```

to:

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033657/gulp-cdnizer-not-replacing-source-links

Comment: nope, I used above link to get the JS files replacement working, mine question is about CSS link tags replacement not working with the cdnizer.